# Using multiple parameters in multiple ways

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, parameters

I have a Sql table with columns. The columns include Name, EmpNum, Status, Dept, Shift, HireDate, TerminatedDate. I would like to create a query that would allow me to query this data using any parameter option available. So Name in(@Name), EmpNum in(@EmpNum), HireDate between @HireStart and @HireEnd, etc. But not all options will be used every time. I tried using "Like", but that did not help with my Date parameters. I'm not sure what to use. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Select *
FROM EmployeeData
Where Name like isnull(@Name,'%') and EmpNum like isnull(@EmpNum,'%')
```

Comment: Suggested reading: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic like this:

```
where (name = @name or @name is null) and
      (empnum = @empnum or @empnum is null) and
      . . .
```

This works for single values.  If you really want lists, you can use:

```
where (name in (select value from string_split(@name, ',') or @name is null) and
      (empnum in (select value from string_split(@empnum, ',') or @empnum is null)
```

Comment: How would the syntax be for the Start Dates and End Dates? where ((TermDate between TermStart and TermEnd) or (TermStart is null or TermEnd is null))